# C++: A general way for an object to notify its owner to destroy itself?

Tags: c++, oop, object

Assume that an ojbect creates and owns (e.g., unique_ptr) a member object. The member object is notified by an asynchronous event by a callback function from outside and when there is an 'end' event, the object can be destroyed. What is the general way for the member object to inform  the owner object that the member object can be destroyed now?

The callback function also needs to return a value. Please look at the simplified version of the code:

```
bool Child::OnNotified(event) {
 if (event == "END") {
   parent->KillMe(this); // how to this?
   return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

Comment: Have something like a `bool toBeDeleted() const;` in your `Child` class.

Comment: You need to clarify what this `parent` is. Is it a member variable pointer to some object, which aggregates `Child` instances? Or are you referring to the base class instance?

Comment: Changed 'parent' to 'owner' for the clarification. No inheritance is involved here.

Comment: You can ask an owner object to delete yourself, which is legal but tricky business since the object will be blown out from under you. After the deletion no further references should be made to any member variable or virtual function in the deleted object. The simplified version of your code doesn't do this, and is therefore correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you will not like answer but it's a matter of ownership. If an object `A` owns object `B`, `B` should **only** be destroyed by `A`. So your "async call" should be handled by `A` or another member of `A` telling `A` to delete `B`.

Every other other way of destroying `B` is basically a hack. In short: don't kill `A` if owned by some other class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *general* way to do this.  The usual way is for the `Child` constructor to take a pointer/reference to the `Owner` class (it looks like you already do this), and then call a function of the `Owner` which instructs the owner to delete the child.

As noted in the comments, the child function then needs to be very careful about what it touches, because the object has been deleted.

If you don't want to make `Child` a friend of `Owner`, but also don't want anyone other than `Child` calling this function, you can provide an interface which `Owner` derives from *privately*, and then pass `Child` a pointer to this private interface instead.